# Every onto map $f$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)+f(x)f(y)$,$f : \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0 \to\Bbb{Z}/2$ is represented by some prime number $p$ and $f=(p\mid-)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $(n \mid x)$ mean $1$ if $n \mid x$ and $0$ otherwise.

Let $f = (p\mid -)$ then $f: \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0 \to \Bbb{Z}/2$ is surjective and only satisfies

$$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) + f(x)f(y), \ \forall x,y \in \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$$

because $p$ is a prime number. I.e. if $p$ were not prime then it would fail to hold that when $p\mid xy$ then $p \mid x$ or $p\mid y$ in general.

The surjectivity part rules out $p = 0, 1$.  I'm wondering if a converse is true, i.e. for any such surjective map $f$, does there exist a prime $p$ such that $f = (p \mid -)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll omit the surjectivity condition, because the analysis isn't much harder in this case.*

First, let's deal with $f(1)$.

If $f(1) = 0$, then $\forall x\,\, f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=f(x)+f(1)+f(x)f(1)=f(x)$. So, no new relations are gained.

If $f(1) = 1$, then $\forall x\,\, f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=f(x)+f(1)+f(x)f(1)=f(x)+1+f(x) = 1$. Thus, in this case $\forall x\,\, f(x)=1$.

Now, assume that $f(1)=0$. The expression $f(x)+f(y)+f(x)f(y)$ is the standard realization of disjunction (logical or) in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ arithmetic (which you probably already know, but it's nice to stress this explicitly); its value is $1$ precisely when at least one of $f(x),f(y)$ is $1$.

What it means is that the value of $f(n)$ is exactly determined by the values of $f(p)$ for $p | n$. So, pick any subset $S$ of primes (even empty or infinite) and define $f(x) = 1$ iff $\exists p\in S\,\,p|x$. It is then a simple induction argument that $f(x)$ so defined satisfies the desired relation.

Answer (score 3):

No, $f$ is not necessarily of this form. The map
$$g:=1+f:\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb Z_2$$ is onto iff $f$ is, and the equation on $f$ is equivalent to
$$g(xy)=g(x)g(y).$$
Therefore, $g$ is given by: for a fixed nonempty set $A$ of primes (the primes on which $g$ vanishes) $g(n)=0$ iff some $p\in A$ divides $n.$

As a result,
$f(n)=1$ if some $p\in A$ divides $n$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: An empty set of primes works too (in which case $\forall x \, f(x)=0$). There's also the case of $\forall x \, f(x)=1$, which isn't covered by a set-of-primes construction.

Comment: The OP excluded these two cases by requiring $f$ to be onto.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that, my apologoies!